# What web programming language is this?

Tags: html, templates, web, templating, templating-engine

I've been looking through the Netgear firmware source for some of the firmwares and while looking at the web directories and HTML files in the source, I've noticed most or all of the HTML files have something similar to this at the top or at random positions in the page:

`<% http_header("style/form.css", "/funcs.js", "/upnp.js") %> <% body_header("_upnp", "UPNP_upnp.htm", "upnp") %>`

It looks like some sort of templating engine/language but I'm not sure what. Just thought this would be interesting to know. If anybody has any information, please leave a response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a custom scripting language modelled after ASP, and referred to internally as "ASP". The source code for the interpreter is missing from [the Netgear source dump](https://github.com/paul-chambers/netgear-r7800/tree/master/git_home/net-cgi.git) (argh!), but [the Makefile](https://github.com/paul-chambers/netgear-r7800/blob/master/git_home/net-cgi.git/src/Makefile) mentions a number of files with "ASP" in their name, and the binary includes similarly named methods, such as:

```
asp_bridge_mode_gateway
asp_wds_enable
asp_wla_wps
asp_dns_check_host
asp_check_hijack_status
asp_show_devices
```

Comment: I was doing more research into this and found this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e26694/about_idoc_script.htm#BCEEGGHE is this in anyway related?

Comment: @DrewMarkel Unrelated. Oracle Fusion Middleware is a Java component which is used with Oracle WebLogic Server -- a single license for WebLogic alone costs more than the entire Netgear device, and the WebLogic server wouldn't even fit in the flash memory of most embedded devices.